# MixItUp filter with already selected content when page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mixitup

I am using MixItUp (https://www.kunkalabs.com/mixitup/) for a small project to filter some Events.

Now the following I would like to achieve: When the user comes from a specific page the content should already be filtered. In my case I have a HTML select option field where the user can select special types of the event.

#### What I have done so far:

I made special links with content I need for setting the filter. For example

```
http://link.de/?filter=blueberries
```

With Javascript / jQuery I now select the option.

```
$('select option[value=".'+URLSELECTION+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

But somehow the MixItUp is not filtering when I make the selection via jQuery. Only if I click it the filter is set. So the selection now is correct, but MixItUp does not trigger the filter.

What can I do to tell MixItUp that it should start filtering the list based on the selected option?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getParam(param) {
      var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
      for (var i=0;i<url.length;i++) {
             var params = url[i].split("=");
             if(params[0] == param)
              return params[1];
      }
      return false;
    }
    var URLSELECTION = getParam("filter");
    $("select option[value='"+ URLSELECTION +"']").attr('selected','selected');
});        
</script>
```

Comment: The selection works fine! I get the option selected which I send via the URL. So this works fine. But MixItUp is not filtering when the select-field is selected via jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using this code:

```
var mixer = mixitup(containerEl, {
   load: {
       filter: '.blueberries'
   }
});
```

I have not tested it but that's what the docs said. https://www.kunkalabs.com/tutorials/filtering-and-sorting-on-load/